# Why output of following code is x=0 x=20?

Tags: java, variables, overriding

```
class Parent 

{

protected int x = 10;

public Parent() 

{

    foo();
    }
    public void foo()
    {
         System.out.printf("x = %d ", x);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent 

{

private int x = 20;

public void foo() 

{

    System.out.printf("x = %d ", x);

    }

}
public class Main

{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        Parent p=new Child();

        p.foo();

        }

}
```

Comment: what's ur question?

Comment: Is the output of your code both 0 and 20 or just 20?

Comment: If it really is x=0 and not x=10, that's interesting.  I would have assumed that the assignment occurred before the ctor of `Parent` was called.

Comment: It's both x=0 x=20

Comment: @Randhawa Yes, scroll down and look at the main method.  `foo()` is called again in main.

Comment: The answer is *shadows*. Variables shadows. Remove `private int x = 20` from `Child`.

Comment: So `x` in `Child` shadows the Parent?  I would have assumed that `x` did something like overriding since `Parent.x` is protected.

Comment: Yes it make shadow but why output is x=0 before 20?

Comment: @Ganesh Because the ctor of `Child` (including the assignment, which effectively happens in a synthetic ctor) hasn't run yet, so the x in `Parent` is actually the x in `Child`, which hasn't been assigned a value yet.

Comment: Thanks, but why it takes 0 and why not any garbage value?

Comment: The initial value of all fields (not local variables or parameters) in Java is 0/null/false.  It has to do with the way memory is initialized in Java before it is allocated to object memory.

Comment: @Ganesh Java is not C. The default initial value of an `int` is `0`. Your field initialization `protected int x = 10;` is syntactic sugar. Each field initialization assignment is copied into **all** constructor bodies.

Comment: @Ganesh Because default value for int is 0

Comment: Yes got it thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `0` because that is the default value of an `int`, and your constructor hasn't yet *run*. You are also shadowing your variable `x` in `Child`. Further, there isn't an implicit `super` invocation for anything except constructors. I think you wanted / expected something like,

```
public class Parent {
    private int x = 10; // <-- this also works if protected

    public void foo() {
        System.out.printf("x = %d ", x);        
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private int x = 20;

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        super.foo();
        System.out.printf("x = %d ", x);
    }
}
```

With those changes I get

```
x = 10 x = 20
```

Note that the `Override` annotation is optional (but a good practice when you  *override* an implementation).

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

Will call the constructor in the parent.

The constructor in the parent calls the method `foo()`
The method `foo()` is in both the class **Parent** and **Child**

Since you have instantiated the Child class, the method call `foo()` in the parent calls the method `foo()` in the child class.

After you call `p.foo()`, x is assigned to **20**
While the child class is still not instantiated which has an undeclared **integer x** which prints **0**.